# Uno WinUI 3.0 Template: different namespaces in UWP and Droid

Tags: uno-platform

I am having issues with the WinUI-template on Uno-platform. For example when implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface from the Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data namespace (which I guess should be correct), the app works on UWP but doesn't build for the Droid target. Using the System.ComponentModel namespace (which should be outdated for WinUI) the app builds and runs for the Droid target, but it doesn't work on the UWP target (meaning that the notifications aren't handled by the UI).

It seems that there is a mixup in the provided solution template regarding the different targets. I used these instructions to create the solution: [Templates for Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-dotnet-new.html#uno-platform-blank-application-for-winui-30---preview)

Also I am experiencing differences on the targets UWP, Droid and Wasm. E.g. ItemsControl.ItemsSource binding to an ObservableCollection works (updates the UI) on Droid and Wasm, but not on UWP. Events fired from an AutoSuggestBox are different on Droid than on UWP, etc.

Updating the nuget-packages several times during the last 3 weeks fixed some of the initial problems, but still the solution doesn't seem to be fully stable. Actually when updating all nuget-packages as of today, the app won't run on Droid anymore, stating that a library is missing at runtime.

Any ideas how to fix these issues and get a stable solution with the same behavior on Droid, UWP and Wasm?

Answer (score 1):

At present time, the [UWP for Win3.0 is not well supported](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md#winui-30-feature-roadmap) (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not properly mapped) and only the Desktop template is properly supported.

If you use the current `unoapp-winui` template (as of Uno Platform 3.5), the Windows projects target WinUI 3 Desktop.